# ASP.NET MVC DropDownlist event to partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist like

```
@Html.DropDownList("ProjectsList")
```

and a link is near it

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Change Project", "ChangeProject", new { code = param }, new { id = "myLink2" })
```

and also a dropdown list for DB names which is accordingly changing to the previous list

```
@Html.DropDownList("Databaselist")
```

What I want is when I click the **Change Project** link it will work the ChangeProject function on c# with selected dropdownlist parameter(I used select2 dd list) and run the **"GetDbList"** function on c#

Comment: Create a form that post a model to the backend that includes the selected values from each dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to manage from server side rendering because if some how you got your dropdownlist value inside actionlink that will be only the value that selected on page load.

So the best ways to get dynamics values like you are looking for is to use script.

`<a class="ChangeProject" href="#">Change Project</a>`

```
$('.ChangeProject').on('click', function(){
    var url = '@Url.Action("project", "GetDbList", new { id= "----" })';
    url = url.replace("----", $('#ProjectsList').val()); //here you will get selected id from dropwon
    window.location = url;
});
```

Comment: I split it to 2 partial view now I can get the index, how can I refresh the second dropdownlist(its also partial view)

Comment: for that u have to use onChange method of first dropdown and when it chnages pick the selected value using jquery or javascript and choose the value inside second dropdown by adding if else etc

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use javascript for this (this code can inspire you to solve):

```
<ul>
  <li><a onClick="myTestFunction(this)">ID1</a></li>
  <li><a onClick="myTestFunction(this)">ID2</a></li>
  <li><a onClick="myTestFunction(this)">ID3</a></li>
  <li><a onClick="myTestFunction(this)">ID4</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function myTestFunction(e)
{
///THERE U CAN IMPLEMENT CODE wich must update link for a tag or do some redirect 

  ///alert(e.textContent);
  var getAtagContent=e.textContent;
  window.location = "/ChangeProject?id="+getAtagContent;
}
</script>
```